# how to use jwt auth method to login user from android app to wordpress website?

Tags: android, android-volley, wordpress-rest-api, jwt, wordpress-json-api

I want to login and sign up the user from android app, i already know that should install some plugins on the word-press website.

I tried to use open source project but it didn't work Here's [login and signup using wp-rest api](https://github.com/AlexBordei/Android-login-and-register-based-on-WordPress-REST-API)

I need guidance on the requests i will send from client side  and is there app secret or password that i need to generate to authenticate the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin, and follow the instruction in the page:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Comment: i did and send request from the app to get the token the response is 404